# Is this query-string parser bug-free?

Tags: javascript, parsing

I tried to implement a definitive, reliable URL query string parser that handles every corner case:

- it tries to be efficient by avoiding regex
- it takes full URLs or just query strings (as long as the query string begins with a question mark)
- it ignores the hash value
- it handles multiple equal parameter names
- it handles parameter names that equal built-in JavaScript methods and keywords

What do you think - did I miss something?

```
function parseURLParams(url) {
  if (url === null) return;

  var queryStart = url.indexOf("?") + 1,
      queryEnd   = url.indexOf("#") + 1 || url.length + 1,
      query      = url.slice(queryStart, queryEnd - 1);

  if (query === url || query === "") return;

  var params = {}, 
      nvPairs = query.replace(/\+/g, " ").split("&");

  for (var i=0; i<nvPairs.length; i++) {
    var nv = nvPairs[i],
        eq = nv.indexOf("=") + 1 || nv.length + 1,
        n  = decodeURIComponent( nv.slice(0, eq - 1) ),
        v  = decodeURIComponent( nv.slice(eq) );
    if ( n !== "" ) {
      if ( !Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(params, n) ) {
        params[n] = [];
      }
      params[n].push(v);
    }
  }
  return params;
}
```

It returns an object of arrays for parsed URLs with query strings and `undefined` if a query string could not be identified.

I used this in an [answer over at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/814613/18771).

Comment: Deleted my answer - I missed that line, sorry! :-) You might still want to take a look at [my other answer over at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript/2880929#2880929).  Interesting how those questions are so similar, posted less than a month apart and the votes are astoundingly different.  I blame the `[jquery]` tag.

Comment: @Andy: Thanks for the cross-reference. I think the jQuery tag might have had an influence. ;) Especially since the 200+ votes answer is essentially flawed.

Comment: @Andy: And, I'm sorry to say, so is your's. ;) Here's an improved version in your spirit: http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/APXH3/ :-) (It still has the problem of not handling multiple parameters of the same name)

Comment: @Tomalak: Now you have me intrigued :-P what is the flaw you spotted?  Near as I can tell, the only difference is that you perform a global replace for `+` on the entire string (which may be more efficient), and you've allowed for a string to be passed instead of using the current URL, but I can't spot any differences beyond those.  I decided not to bloat my answer by supporting dupe parameters, as that practice is a rare one.  However, I did link to a proof-of-concept example that would parse the URL in a similar style to how PHP would handle it.

Comment: @Andy Oh, you're right. If you just work on `window.location.search` and ignore duplicate params, your original version is fine, too. I was testing with full URLs; your key/value regex did not work with them. So, uhm... At least your approach could be more simplified (no nested function `d()`). :-P

Comment: @Tomalak: I'll take it under consideration for my next edit ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Is it bug free?  No.

These two corner-cases have been missed:

1. parameter values containing '=', i.e. 'example.com?foo==bar' (double equals) or '?foo=k=v'
2. cannot handle parameters called 'toString' and 'valueOf' (amongst others.)

The first may well count as malformed URL, but Chrome handles it and pass through == unencoded in `location.search`.  To handle this, go back to basic `indexOf` usage.

The second problem's just pedantic really.  You could try and work around it using `!params.hasOwnProperty(n)` instead of `!(n in params)`, but you'll still get stuck if someone passes a parameter called `hasOwnProperty`.  The only way I see around this is to fall back to some dire array-based collection populated something like:

```
var keys = [], params = [];
for (...) {
    var n = ..., v = ...;
    var i = keys.indexOf(n);
    if (i >= 0) {
        if (!(params[i] instanceof Array)) {
            params[i] = [params[i]];
        }
        params.push(v);
    } else {
        params[i] = v;
        keys.push(n);
    }
}
```

I guess you'd then have to resort to returning an array of arrays rather than an object.  i.e. each element of the array returned would either be `[key, value]` or `[key, [values]]`, although client *might* find it easier to work with if you returned something like `[key, value1, value2, ...]` (which caters nicely for properties without values.)

Comment: Wow, great answer. :-) I'll come up with an improved version.

Comment: See modified answer. I've decided not to go down the array-of-arrays route as this is highly impractical.

Comment: I like the way you handle and call hasOwnProperty - very nice.

Comment: Of course it would still be broken "downstream" - the object returned would have its `hasOwnProperty` overwritten. But the function would not break. Anything else that comes to mind? Efficiency-wise maybe? It seems a little bloated to me...

Comment: Try `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(params, n)`

Answer (score 2):

you could do a null check on the url argument because the following will throw an exception.

```
parseURLParams(null);
```

Comment: Good point. Done.

Answer (score 1):

Seems a tiny bit over-engineered. Something like this should work just as well, and addresses searlea's points in his answer:

```
function parseURLParams(url) {
  var out = {}; 
  (url.split('?')[1] || url).split('#')[0].split('&').forEach(function(p) { 
    var kv = p.match(/([^=]*)=?(.*)/), 
        k = decodeURIComponent(kv[1]), 
        v = decodeURIComponent(kv[2] || ''); 
    hasOwnProperty.call(out, k) ? out[k].push(v) : out[k] = [v]; 
  });
  return out;
}
```

The regex match is only needed if you want to support equals signs in values, otherwise you can use `split` and the indices 0 and 1.

The main (only?) difference is that pretty much any string will be treated as a viable query -- if there are no equals signs or ampersands, it's a query with just one key and no value.

Comment: Yikes, just realized how old this question is =/

Comment: Hm. That's a little too compressed for my tastes. I like less "clever" code. Oh and `forEach()` is not portable.

Comment: Fair enough. I felt the same way about `forEach` and ES5-only features for a long time, but I figure we're at the point by now where ES5 is "normal" and anything else is "legacy," and can be shimmed or whatever if legacy support is needed.

Comment: Right, adding `forEach()` to the array prototype if necessary is not very difficult, you just have to remember to do it. I suppose most people use some sort of JS library anyway.